# How to fetch only the necessary contents from two queries in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

i have two queries combined together as one nested query.when i run the queries separately they show me the correct result but when they are joined together,i get the same employee name multiple times with way too many values.please note that the **emp_id** column in emp_sec table is null.i only need to get the section name from **emp_sec** table.

what i would like to get from the query is to find the employees with the section names and given that the same employee name to be displayed once or twice or thrice but not more than that.

table structures :

```
SQL> desc hw_nat a
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 ISS_NO                                   VARCHAR2(6)
 LOC_CD                                   VARCHAR2(2)
 CAT_CD                                   VARCHAR2(2)
 TYP_CD                                   VARCHAR2(3)
 BD_CD                                    VARCHAR2(3)
 MOD_NO                                   VARCHAR2(3)
 ISS_QTY                                  NUMBER(10,2)
 CSL_NO                                   VARCHAR2(20)
 IEMP_ID                                  VARCHAR2(4)
 ISS_TYP                                  VARCHAR2(1)
 ISS_DT                                   DATE
 RV_NO                                    VARCHAR2(6)
 REMP_ID                                  VARCHAR2(4)
 H_GRP                                    VARCHAR2(1)
 FLAG                                     VARCHAR2(1)
 REQ_NO                                   VARCHAR2(6)
 WK_DT                                    DATE
 COM_CD                                   VARCHAR2(2)
 AC_SL                                    VARCHAR2(15)
 CALL_NO                                  VARCHAR2(5)


SQL> desc hw_emp b
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 EMP_ID                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)
 EMP_NM                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(40)
 GRD_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(3)
 DESG_CD                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 DIV_CD                                   VARCHAR2(1)
 DEPT_CD                                  VARCHAR2(2)
 SEC_CD                                   VARCHAR2(3)
 S_DT                                     DATE
 E_DT                                     DATE
 STATUS                                   VARCHAR2(1)
 MOB                                      VARCHAR2(14)
 TEL                                      VARCHAR2(14)
 COM_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> desc emp_sec c
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 COM_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
 SEC_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 DIV_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
 DEPT_CD                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 SEC_NM                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(60)
 WK_DT                           NOT NULL DATE
 EMP_ID                                   VARCHAR2(5)
 USER_ID                                  VARCHAR2(5)


SQL> desc hw_cat d
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 CAT_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 CAT_NM                                   VARCHAR2(40)

SQL> 
SQL> desc hw_typ e
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 CAT_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 TYP_CD                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(3)
 TYP_NM                                   VARCHAR2(40)

 SQL>
```

QUERY with Results

```
select distinct X.iemp_id,X.emp_nm,X.sec_cd,Y.sec_nm,X.cat_nm,X.typ_nm,X.bd_cd,X.mod_no,X.csl_no,X.remp_id FROM
(select distinct a.iemp_id,b.emp_nm,b.sec_cd,d.cat_nm,e.typ_nm,a.bd_cd,a.mod_no,a.csl_no,a.remp_id
from hw_nat a,hw_emp b,hw_cat d,hw_typ e,company f
where a.iemp_id = b.emp_id
and a.ISS_TYP not in ('5','6','7','B','T','L','R')
--and c.sec_nm = :SEC
--and a.cat_cd = :cat_code
and d.cat_cd = e.cat_cd
and a.typ_cd = e.typ_cd
and a.bd_cd = '006'
and a.cat_cd = d.cat_cd
and f.com_cd = '01'
--and a.iemp_id = c.emp_id
--and b.sec_cd = c.sec_cd
--and a.remp_id = '2UH7'
order by 6) X,
(select distinct sec_cd,sec_nm from emp_sec 
order by sec_cd) Y
where x.sec_cd = y.sec_cd
order by X.iemp_id,X.emp_nm,X.sec_cd,Y.sec_nm
```

please have a look at the screenshots i have attached here.thanks.

[image: main_query]

What i would like to get from the first query i have posted above with section name from **emp_sec** table :

[image: Q2]

Comment: I guess you photoshop second image to match your desire result?

Comment: You should provide a sample data and desire output. And if you provide a [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/256da/8) we can find an answer much easier.

Comment: Honestly, your query is a bit of a mess. In the first part you select from a  table called company, which you don't join to any other table and you don't use any of it's columns anywhere. Why is it there at all?

Comment: it is really hard to understand your query.could you explain?

Comment: i found the solution to my query myself.thanks for all your help.